# train two keras models in parallel in python

Tags: python, keras, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to build a function that can train two Keras models in parallel.
My function is something like this:

```
def fit_function(index):
    'some code here'
     print('statrt fitting model1..')
     model_1.fit(X[index],y[index],epochs=1)
     print('statrt fitting model2..')
     model_2.fit(X[index],y[index],epochs=1)
     return
```

Also, I use the multiprocessing library in python:

```
import multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=fit_function, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

after runing this it prints : 'statrt fitting model1..' which means it goes into function
but after this output, it does nothing! program doesn't stop and not giving results.

which part I am doing wrong? I would be really grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple inconsistencies in your code. usually, it helps to give a minimal reproducible code. You also need to check your CPU count if you don't know also you're not doing anything with your model.

Here's a minimal example of training a classifier with different data in parallel. Here I'm assuming you need multiple versions of the model the way you have coded.

```
from sklearn import svm
X = [ [[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]] ]
y = [[0, 1], [1, 0] ]


def fit_function(index, return_models):
  print('statrt fitting model1..')
  print(index)
  clf = svm.SVC()
  clf.fit(X[index], y[index])
  return_models[index] = clf

import multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(f'Number of cpus: {multiprocessing.cpu_count()}')
  jobs = []
  n = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

  manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
  return_models = manager.dict()

  for i in range(0,n):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=fit_function, args=(i, return_models))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    p.join()

  print(return_models)
```